# I can't set a Specific Url in Webview in fragment in android

Tags: android, url, web, view, webview

I have a Problem With Setdata in Webview in android
The Problem Is That I can not set a specific Url in Webview 
For Example I can set http://www.youtube.com but I can not set
http://www.youtube.com/user/androiddevelopers I do not know what to do and why 
It's not working

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
public FragmentA() {
    Log.i("in :","on cons");
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);

    WebView wv = (WebView)mainView.findViewById(R.id.url);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


    wv.loadUrl("here is my problem");

    return mainView;


}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        if(url.contains("here is where i will put the url to check") == true) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        }
        return true;

    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: You do not "upload URL". No way.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski thank you for your answer .. i was mean that i can't     setData(Uri.parse(Url)); with what i wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem.

`webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});`